# How to Export data into excel in laravel 8 with maatwebsite-excel. excel not exporting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, maatwebsite-excel

I have used maatwebsite-excel but i am getting issue while exporting. This is my Controller.

```
public function exportOneTimePayments(){  
    
    return Excel::download(new ExportOneTimePayments, 'one-time-payments-'.date("Y-m-d").'.csv'); 
}
```

And This is my export Class

```
class ExportOneTimePayments implements FromQuery, WithHeadings, WithMapping {   

public function query()
{   
    return SubscriptionOneTimePayment::query()  
        when(request()->pg_subscription_id,function($query){
            $query->whereHas('subscription', function ($q){
                $q->where('pg_subscription_id', request()->pg_subscription_id);
            }); 
        }) 
        ->orderBy('id','desc')
        ->get();  
} 

public function batchSize(): int
{ 
    return 1000;
} }
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Is there any error? What is the error?